# spacing in search box

Tags: jquery, keyup, backspace

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#searchInput').keypress(function() 
   {
      if($(this).val() == '')
      {
        $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
      }
      else
      {
        $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
      }

   });
});
```

and i added next to button id "disabled"
now i have a problem.When I press space and click search button, no problem, Everything is fine.But after I pressed space key and pressed backspace , i am clicking search button and it shows results.I couldn't resolve the problem.I want to prevention space initial.

Comment: Your question is mixed up. In the comments below you are asking for something that it is not described in your initial question. Please, provide a proper description of what you are trying to achieve and why you failed to achieve it

Comment: dear alexander i don't want to space in my search box.I want to prevention blank results.UP CODES WORKED BUT WİTH MOUSE-CLICK.it doesn't work with keyboard-enter

Answer (score 1):

Space is not null you should try *$.trim()* function ,
trim will remove all the spaces and give only string without any trailing spaces

```
 $('#searchInput').keypress(function() 
 {
   if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '')
   {
     $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
   }
   else
   {
     $('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
   }
 });
```

Comment: it worked, but when i keyboard press enter, it shows results again

Comment: instead of keypress event add keyup event

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to the problem, even if it is a good idea.

Comment: i added instead of keypress keyup.But when i pressed enter it shows results again

Comment: i am sorry  it works with mouse-click but it doesn't work with keyboard

Comment: i guess we should keyboard disabled too.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarrely, you are running up against some odd browser behaviour. In IE and Webkit browsers, <kbd>backspace</kbd> does not fire a `keypress` event, so the handler is never executed.

In Firefox, however, the function is run *before* the `value` of the element is changed. So when you type <kbd>space</kbd>, the function is run and `value` is still empty. Therefore the button is disabled. Then you press <kbd>backspace</kbd>, and the function is run with `value` is still a one-character string, with a space in it. So the button is enabled.

You need to use `keyup` instead, as this is run in all browsers when <kbd>backspace</kbd> is pressed and it is run *after* the `value` is changed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
        if (this.value == '') {
            $('#button').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }).keyup(); 
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ecad5/1/)

Changes I have made:

- changing `keypress` to `keyup`
- `this.value` rather than `$(this).val()`: much faster
- `prop('disabled', true)` rather than `attr('disabled', true)`: this is the correct function to use and avoids doing the odd `removeAttr`
- adding `keyup()` to the end, so the function is also run when the page is first loaded

Comment: I beg to disagree about the behavior you describe for `keypress`. In short, there's no event whatsoever when you press backspace

Comment: i don't want to space initial

Comment: @Alexander Do you really. Why?

Comment: As I said above, there shouldn't be an event when you press backspace

Comment: @Alexander In all fairness, I think the problem is that I'm using Firefox and you are using a different browser. FF fires `keypress` on backspace, other browsers do not. This is news to me!

Comment: Fair enough, I'm off here. The OP is changing the question on topic and this will take forever

Answer (score 0):

Just a bit minified and use `$.trim` to prevent *`enabling`* by whitespace:

```
$('#searchInput').keyup(function () {
       $('#button').prop('disabled', !$.trim(this.value));
}).keyup();
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tS4zF/)